# C++ Determine if a file is older than int hours

Tags: c++, windows

I have an MFC application where I need to determine if a file's last write time is older than n hours.

I thought there was a method to get total seconds from either system or file time, but I ended up coding this method which works, but there might be a leaner method.

```
bool FileOlderThanHours(HANDLE hFile, int hours)
{
    FILETIME ftCreate, ftLastAccess, ftLastWrite;
    SYSTEMTIME stNow, stFile;
    GetSystemTime(&stNow);  
    if (!GetFileTime(hFile, &ftCreate, &ftLastAccess, &ftLastWrite))
        return false;
    if (!FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftLastWrite, &stFile))
        return false;
    COleDateTime oleNow(stNow.wYear, stNow.wMonth, stNow.wDay, stNow.wHour, 
    stNow.wMinute, stNow.wSecond);
    COleDateTime oleFile(stFile.wYear, stFile.wMonth, stFile.wDay, stFile.wHour, 
    stFile.wMinute, stFile.wSecond);
    COleDateTimeSpan timeDiff = oleNow - oleFile;
    double totHours = timeDiff.GetTotalHours();
    return (totHours > hours);
}
```

If someone knows a leaner way, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing the return type on the function.

Comment: my bad--I copied this method from my class and omitted the type along with the ... ClassName:: prefix.

Comment: Please don't edit or append code in the question after it has been reviewed. For details, see: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c

Comment: In addition to what user673679 stated: incorporating feedback from answers goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MFC, the [`CFile::GetStatus`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfile-class?view=msvc-170) method lets you query the creation, modification or access time of a file.

Code to use it would look something like:

```
CTime getModificationTIme(const LPCTSTR filename)
/* Returns the last modification time of the requested file.  The
 * filename must be a null-terminated wide string.
 */
{
  CFileStatus inputFileStatus;
  if (!CFile::GetStatus( filename, inputFileStatus )) {
    // Handle the error, perhaps by throwing an exception. E.g.,
    THROW((CException*) new CCustomException(filename));
  }
  return inputFileStatus.m_mtime;
}
```

In current versions of Windows, the filename is a null-terminated wide string.  Future versions might un-deprecate the `char*` version to accept a UTF-8 filename.

Visual Studio 2017 and up support the standard library’s `<filesystem>` header, of which you can find [an example of usage at cppreference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time)

One major difference between Windows and other systems is that, on Windows, the `<filesystem>` API [uses wide strings to create a `std::filesystem::path`.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/file-system-navigation?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thanks! I implemented the CTime class into my method.

Comment: @netcat Glad it helped! Anyone who copies this later should be sure to notice, my error-handling code was just a dummy.